# Moving from Spring MVC XML files to javaconfig. I am really at a lost with my database XML file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I Moving from Spring MVC XML files to javaconfig. I am really at a lost with my database XML file. I don't know how to get Hibernate4 working and my JBoss JNDI Datasource working.  Can someone please tell me how to make the javaconfig class work like this XML..

Here is my database.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mySQLDB"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.uftwf.inquiry.model.MemberInquiryInformation</value>

            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">${format_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my javaconfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"org.uftwf.inquiry"})
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml")
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/classes/messages";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMVCConfig.class);


    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean()
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.uftwf.inquiry.model");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",  hibernateDialect);
        //hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        //hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");

        //Audit History flags
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean
    public  ViewResolver resolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver url = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        url.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return url;
    }


    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        logger.debug("setting up message source");
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        logger.debug("setting up resource handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        logger.debug("configureDefaultServletHandling");
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");
        b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return b;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestTrackerConfig requestTrackerConfig()
    {
        RequestTrackerConfig tr = new RequestTrackerConfig();
        tr.setPassword("Waiting#$");
        tr.setUrl("https://uftwfrt01-dev.uftmasterad.org/REST/1.0");
        tr.setUser("root");

        return tr;
    }


}
```

I think the parts I am missing are the following but please overcheck my class

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mySQLDB"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />
```

annotate your Configuration class, `WebMVCConfig`, with

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

For

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />
```

Add the package String to your `@ComponentScan` field `basePackages`

For

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />
```

annotate your Configuration class with

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:app.properties")
```

and make your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` `@Bean` method `static`.

For

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mySQLDB"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

[I think you can do](http://www.swiftmind.com/de/2011/06/22/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/)

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/mySQLDB");
}
```

Instead of autowiring your session factory, just call your `@Bean` method

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager()
{
    HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
    return htm;
}
```

Comment: its still giving me that the sessionFactory cant be Autowired

Comment: See edit. What you can do is call the bean method that creates the session factory. Bean does some cool proxying stuff on your bean methods so regardless of how many times you call that method (eg. two beans need the session factory), it'll always return the same instance.

Comment: this is the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor

Comment: Do you have all your hibernate jars on classpath? Check again.

Comment: Actually, @EnableTransactionManager is not a fair replacement for xml annotation. You see, on xml you can define the transactionManager bean name, so no matter if you have another PlatformTransactionManager classes on context, it will still working just fine! On JavaConfig approach, however, a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException will arise!

Comment: @Beccari I think I misunderstand you. The annotation will look for any `PlatformTransactionManager` in the application context. `<tx:annotation-driven />` will be default look for a bean named `transactionManager`. If you've named your bean anything else, it's the XML that will fail.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Notice that TransactionAspectSupport - when no explicit transactionManager is specified (by name) - will getBean by type: this.beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class). Which means, if you have more than one, you have to specify the name! This is only possible on xml. Found right now that in JavaConfig there is one solution: TransactionManagementConfigurer

Comment: @Beccari Right, so if you have a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean with another name, JavaConfig will work, but a default `annotation-driven` will not.

Comment: @Beccari Ah, in the case of more than one, then yes, use the [configurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/TransactionManagementConfigurer.html).